# the specified colorspace format is not supported. falling back on libyuv

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera, avfoundation

I'm currently working on a camera app. Everything worked fine, but when I tried to change the constraints of the Vision View the log suddenly printed this error.

[warning]the specified colorspace format is not supported. falling back on libyuv.

I have no Idea where it comes from and what I should change. Below I'll past the relevant code where I set up the camera.

```
  func initializeCameraSession() {
            //  Set up Values
            
            //1:  Create a new AV Session
//            , xf           , AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate           // Get camera devices
            let devices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .front).devices
            //2:  Select a capture device
            
            avSession.sessionPreset = .low
            do {
                if let captureDevice = devices.first {
                
                    let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)



                    }
                   avSession.beginConfiguration()
                    if avSession.canAddInput(captureDeviceInput) {
                        avSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
                            self.videoDeviceInput = captureDeviceInput
                                
                    } else {
                                print("Couldn't add video device input to the session.")
                                avSession.commitConfiguration()
                                return
                            }
                    avSession.commitConfiguration()
                }
                
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
            //3:  Show output on a preview layer
            let captureOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            captureOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue"))
            captureOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA )]
            avSession.addOutput(captureOutput)
        
            
            let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: avSession)
            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation =  .portrait
            previewLayer.frame = visionView.bounds
            
        
                visionView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                view.bringSubviewToFront(visionView)
                visionView.isHidden = true
            visionView.alpha = 0.0
               avSession.startRunning()
            
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I appreciate that you are wondering. Unfortunately I wasn't able to solve it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue as it was throwing this issue when I was trying to pass in a UIImage to Google Vision. I ended up doing UIImage -> JPEGData -> UIImage and it "fixed" the colourspace issues, whatever they were. Sorry, this won't be much help to you :/

Comment: Are you using sampleBuffer from didOutput sampleBuffer delegate and using sampleBuffer to create VisionImage using VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)?

Comment: @GurjinderSingh Yes I am. Why is that important to know? Thanks for responding

Comment: I'm also seeing the same warning. But instead, I'm creating a VisionImage from UIImage. When I create it from a sampleBuffer, I don't see the warnings. But my setup kind of dictates that I need to use UIImage.